# iOS detect NewRelic errors when it tries to report data

Tags: ios, newrelic, nserror

I want to know in my app when NewRelic tries to send data and it fails for any reason, for example, when there is no internet connection it gets the error

```
NRMAHarvesterConnection.m:101   -[NRMAHarvesterConnection send:]
Failed to retrieve collector response: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x7fa044e1a360 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa044e26a10 "The Internet connection appears to be offline.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mobile-collector.newrelic.com/mobile/v2/data, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mobile-collector.newrelic.com/mobile/v2/data, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}
```

NewRelic prints this error to the console, so It must be detecting this kind of errors.

I want to know when this kind of errors happen and what the error was so I can log it

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in a case when error code is below 400, NewRelic doesn't send automatic error reports. So you need to handle this case by yourself, for example:

```
[NewRelic noticeNetworkFailureForURL:(NSURL *)url
                      httpMethod:(NSString*)httpMethod
                       withTimer:(NRTimer *)timer
                  andFailureCode:(NSInteger)iOSFailureCode];
```

But from my opinion, you should track such client-dependent events, as lack of internet connection. NewRelic gives you possibility to check if your endpoints are normally reachable, or returning HTTP error codes. It is very useful while tracking state of CDN nodes. In other words: track everything which returns HTTP error code, but don't track Cocoa error codes.